# Mootools wait with Fx.Morph start

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-fx

I am trying to get `var effect = new Fx.Morph(testMorph, {` to wait/delay 2 seconds before starting.
(**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4EU4/)**)

But when I try `.wait(2000)` or `.delay(2000)`, or even `.wait(2000, effect)` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'delay'`

Any ideas how to get this working?

Code I'm using:

```
var testMorph = document.id('testMorph');
var effect = new Fx.Morph(testMorph, {
    transition: 'back:out',
    duration: 900,
    link: 'chain'
}).start({
    'top': 20,
    'opacity': 1
}).start({
    'border-color': '#A80025',
    'color': '#A80025'
});
effect.delay(2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `chain()` and `delay()` to achieve the desired effect.

```
new Fx.Morph(testMorph, {
    transition: 'back:out',
    duration: 900,
    link: 'chain'
}).start().chain(function(){
    this.start.delay(2000,effect,{
        //first
    });
}).chain(function(){
    this.start({
        //second
    });
});
```

The `chain()` adds another effect at the end of the current one.
The first effect is simply start() with an empty effect, to provide context to our chain of events.

It is then chained to the delayed event, using the `start.delay()` method (`delay()` is a property of `Function`).

This, in turn, is chained to your other effect.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4EU4/1/).